# npm run build generates Unhandled rejection Error: SourceMap

Tags: vue.js

Using vue CLI, running npm run build generates 
'Unhandled rejection Error: "." is not in SourceMap

Added 'vue.config.js' file to project with body similar to the below.

```
module.exports = {
  productionSourceMap: false
}
```

This seems to have resolved the issue but would like to know the true culprit and possibly fix the issue without the workaround

The error looks like the following

```
Unhandled rejection Error: "." is not in the SourceMap.
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_sourceContentFor [as sourceContentFor] (C:\Projects\UI\test-repo-client\node_modules\webpack-sources\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-consumer.js:753:13)
```

Would prefer not to use the flag 'productionSourceMap'

Comment: Same here. And I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed for me using `npm update`

Updated some libs including :
+ @vue/cli-service@3.10.0

and terser to v4.1.4